# SQL ordered by Elapsed Time in AWR report

Tags: oracle, awr

I was trying to analyze the `AWR` report generated for a particular process with a duration of one hour. I am trying to find out which query is taking much time 
to while running the process.

When I have gone through the report, I can see `SQL ordered by Gets`,`SQL ordered by CPU Time`,`SQL ordered by Executions`,`SQL ordered by Parse Calls`,
`SQL ordered by Sharable Memory`,`SQL ordered by Elapsed Time` etc.

I can see the `SQL Text` from the table `SQL ordered by Elapsed Time`.

My question: Is this the right way to identify the expensive query ? Please advise in this regard.

```
Elapsed Time (s)    SQL Text
19,477.05            select abc.....
7,644.04             select def...
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Ordered by Elapsed Time` , includes SQL statements that took significant execution time during processing.We have to look at `Executions`,`Elapsed time per Exec (s)` etc. along with `Elapsed time` to analyze.

For example,a query has low `Executions` and high `Elapsed time per Exec (s)` and this query could be a candidate for troubleshooting or optimizations.

The best reference I found so far: http://www.dbas-oracle.com/2013/05/10-steps-to-analyze-awr-report-in-oracle.html

Answer (score 0):

AWR  is used to see database health. So, I think this is not the good tools to trace a process.

You should use other tools like sql_trace (with tkprof) or dbms_profiler. It will concenrate on your own process.
If you are using sql_trace, you need to connect to the server (or ask to the dba tem) to analyse the trace.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Ordered by Elapsed time you always need to check the Query which is having low Execution numbers and higher Elapsed time . This would always be the problematic Query . Since Elapsed time is the defined task for a respective Query in this case if it is higher with less number of Executions it means that for some reason the Query is performing not up to expectations .

Answer (score 0):

There is some parameter need to check so we are find issue in progress.

**Buffer get** is less expensive than physical read because database has to work harder (and more) to get the data. Basically time it would have taken if available in buffer cache + time actually taken to find out from physical block.

If you suspect that excessive parsing is hurting your **database’s performance**:

1. check “time model statistics” section (hard parse elapsed time, parse time elapsed etc.)
2. see if there are any signs of library cache contention in the top-5 events
3. see if CPU is an issue.

Establishing a new database connection is also expensive (and even more expensive in case of audit or triggers).
**“Logon storms”** are known to create very serious performance problems.
If you suspect that high number of logons is degrading your performance, check “connection management elapsed time” in “Time model statistics”.

**Soft Parsing** being low indicates bind variable and versioning issues. With 99.25 % for the soft parse meaning that about 0.75 % (100 – soft parse) is happening for hard parsing. Low hard parse is good for us.

If Latch Hit % is <99%, you may have a latch problem. Tune latches to reduce cache contention.

**Library hit** % is great when it is near 100%. If this was under 95% we would investigate the size of the shared pool.
In this ration is low then we may need to:

• Increase the SHARED_POOL_SIZE init parameter.

• CURSOR_SHARING may need to be set to FORCE.

• SHARED_POOL_RESERVED_SIZE may be too small.

• Inefficient sharing of SQL, PLSQL or JAVA code.

• Insufficient use of bind variables